# Источник информации об ассемблере DirectX-а

Tags: windows, ассемблер, directx, шейдеры, информация

В общем, изучаю язык ассемблера DirectX-а (пока что конкретно для DirectX 9). Пока что изучаю по книге «`"Learn Vertex and Pixel Shader Programming with DirectX 9" - James C. Leiterman`» (англ. версию, русской не нашёл).
Дело в том, что, изучив (более-менее) как работает **ассемблер DirectX-а**, я столкнулся с тем что я не знаю как этот код собрать (ассемблировать). В вышеупомянутой книжке написан лишь «список приложений-инструметнов для работы с шейдерами», но не сказано **ассемблируют** ли они код или просто компилируют высокоуровневый код. И если ассемблируют, то ещё и не сказано как ими пользоваться.

Вот список приведённых в той книге приложений-инструментов, цитирую:

> When assembling or compiling your shader code, you will most likely be using one of the following tools:
>
> - nvasm.exe: nVidia –V&P Macro Assembler.
> - psa.exe: Direct3D 8 Pixel Shader Assembler.
> - vsa.exe: Direct3D 8 Vertex Shader Assembler.
> - xsasm.exe: Xbox Shader Assembler
> - cg.exe: Cg (C for graphics) compiler is limited in scope to the hardware platform.
> - fxc.exe: HLSL compiler provided with DX9 SDK, which optimizes code for all hardware platforms.
> - RenderMonkey.exe: RenderMonkey.
>
> One noteworthy item is that development of nvasm has stalled, so it only supports ps.1.3 and thus has limited use.

(программы `psa.exe` и `vsa.exe` не нашёл в папке `Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)`. Там я нашел только `fxc.exe` и в интернете искал информацию как использовать этот `fxc.exe` но там пишут что эта программа для компилирования шейдеров, написанных на [`HLSL`](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLSL), а это мне не нужно. Остальное не искал потому что это не официальные программы от `Microsoft`, и поэтому они могут прекратить поддержку, и, короче, нафиг надо левые приложения если есть от `Microsoft`. Тем более раз уж я под `Windows` программу делаю, то `Microsoft`-ские программы понадёжнее будут. Хотя, если уж совсем не найду официальных, то видимо придётся пользоваться неофициальными, чтобы хоть как-то на всю мощь видеоускоритель/видеокарту использовать)

Короче, я просмотрел много чего в интернете чтобы найти способ собрать код, написанный на **языке ассемблера DirectX-а**, но не нашёл.

Кто нибудь знает источники информации (наиболее понятные, конечно) об ассемблировании шейдеров на **языке ассемблера DirectX-а** (желательно какими-нибудь инструментами от `Microsoft`)? Мне нужно именно о **языке ассемблера DirectX-а**, а не что-то высокоуровневое типа [`HLSL`](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLSL). Так как мне нету толку изучать ассемблер DirectX-а если я его собрать в программу не могу. (Ну и можно сообщить источник информации о программировании на этом ассемблере DirectX-а, если таковой знаете, вдруг вышеупомянутой книги мне не хватит чтобы знать о нём всё что мне нужно, а так хоть знать буду где искать информацию). Если сами знаете как осуществить сборку шейдерного ассемблерного кода, то можете это тоже сообщить (или вместо источника, так как порой всё-таки с чьих-то слов информация может быть эффективнее чем в других источниках).

Comment: Ассемблер входит в HLSL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx9-graphics-reference-asm

Comment: @user7860670, @AlexF, Я понял, исходя из ссылки `Alex F`-а на `Stack Overflow`: **ассемблер** шейдеров DirectX-а поддерживается только до версии модели шейдеров 3.0 (вершинный шейдер версии 3.0 и пиксельный шейдер версии 3.0) которые поддерживаются только с версии `DirectX 9.0c` (да, у них оказывается ещё и буквенно версии отличаются). Поэтому походу мне пока-что видимо подходит (более-менее) эта версия шейдеров 3.0, так как скорее всего поддерживается ещё и следующими после DirectX 9.0c версиями DirectX-а (типо DirectX 10, DirectX 11 и т.д.). Хоть и я это пока что не проверил.

Comment: @user7860670, @AlexF, Но, тем не менее, _остаётся проблема что нет информации как это всё всё-таки ассемблировать_ - это в данных ссылках не описано. И, кстати, @user7860670, в ссылке на `Stack Overflow` спрашивающий сказал что у него fxc.exe вроде как не принимает ничего, кроме языка [`HLSL`](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLSL): `It seems fxc.exe from the Windows SDK does not accept asm shader files.` Так что скорее всего ассемблер DirectX-а входит лишь в документацию HLSL, ну или просто собирается разными программами (не знаю какие там зависимости между HLSL и ассемблером)

Comment: На самом деле этот вопрос похож на проблему XY. ¿Зачем вам вообще понадобился древний DirectX 9 и что-то ассемблировать? Сейчас это нужно разве что если собираетесь патчить чужие шейдеры, либо делаете собственный инструментарий. Используйте DX11 и HLSL.

Comment: @user7860670, Я хочу поддерживать как можно больше устройств. И тех кто пользуется компьютерами с 32-битной `Windows` достаточно много, учитывая что я ещё и лично знаю таких людей кто выбрал такой компьютер осознанно или неосознанно, и у самого стоит дома отлично работающий компьютер с 32-битной `Windows`. Плюс не у всех есть куча денег на покупку дорогого мощного компьютера для работы неоптимизированных программ или нет времени и знаний на запар с его попыткой дёшево собрать (если уметь собрать вообще) (и это всё-равно будет дорого). Моя цель и причина ассемблирования - бешенная оптимизация

Comment: @user7860670, По той же причине, которую я описал в комментарии выше, я хочу поддерживать DirectX 9, особенно, что у самого на ноуте стоит интегрированная видеокарта/видеоускоритель который DirectX 11 не поддерживает (про 10.1 не знаю, но всё-таки DirectX 9 у достаточно многих старых компьютеров это потолок)

Comment: DX11 и HLSL можно использовать на 32 битных компьютерах. А еще у вас явно тяжелый случай крайне преждевременной оптимизации. DirectX 9 уже давно устарел и работает через прослойки обратной совместимости, а fixed function pipeline или примитивные шейдеры не позволяют выжимать производительность из GPU. Кроме того, шейдерный ассемблер вовсе не работает на GPU, как можно было бы подумать по аналогии с x86 ассемблером. На самом деле шейдеры компилируются в промежуточный байткод, а "настоящей" компиляцией занимается драйвер GPU.

Comment: Не знаю, какие у вас обстоятельства, но сейчас реально купить более-менее актуальную карту с толковой поддержкой DX11 на пару к.р. Так что не мучайтесь зря.

Comment: @user7860670, не переживайте, для меня это не особо мучения, да и даже интересно, особенно учитывая что новые устройства всё-равно поддерживают старые архитектуры, команды, и т.д., поэтому письмена кода на DirectX 9 не уйдут зря для тех у кого поддерживаются DirectX более новых версий. Насчёт промежуточного байт-кода в DirectX я знаю, но под "шейдерным ассемблером" я как раз и имею ввиду тонкую настройку команд - то есть не написание кода на высокоуровневом HLSL, а через конкретные команды. Так как оптимизация мне нужна как можно более детальная.

Comment: @user7860670, А насчёт стоимости "железа" - дело не только в этом. Не все **способны позволить (морально)** купить себе устройство даже за 20000, поэтому могут сидеть с относительно древними ПК, а ведь сидеть за ними могут не только они... В мою так сказать "целевую аудиторию" входят в том числе и юные пользователи ПК, а у них - слово "финансы", (во главе с "запретами" и другими проявлениями взаимоотношений с опекунами) может быть лишь очень далёким будущим (на несколько лет вперёд), лишать которого не хочется, так как сам знаю каково это. Короче говоря у меня есть и интерес и причина

Comment: @user7860670, Плюс у меня у самого относительно древний ПК. Покупать необходимый по производительности возможности нет